# iPod Equalizer issue

Tags: ipod

I bought a new gen iPod nano and filled it with my best songs.
But when I connected it to my car's audio jack so the music would play through the speakers,
all of the songs sounded flat and weak. I set the equalizer to what sounded best, but it still sounds awful. Sort of muffled and plain. What did iTunes or the iPod do to my songs that made them this way and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you set equalizer to POP?  Does the sound change?                                                   Are you playing music converted from a CD?  If yes, what import settings did you use?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are actually a number of different things that COULD be wrong. For example, the Auxiliary (or AUX) cord could have been frayed on the inside, or someone might have chipped a bit of their own cord inside which you just didn't notice, or something else had your attention. You might not have pushed the cord in all the way, at the same time, some systems work better with the cord NOT pushed in all the way, in which case I suggest GENTLY and SLOWLY loosening the cord from the hole to see if the sound gets better.

The new nano might have come with a (thankfully rare) defect, so you can try taking it to a Genius bar, or if you call Apple about it, depending on the severity of the problem (and if they have nothing to do and are bored) they might charge you, and send you a new iPod in the mail, and wait for you to send yours back to them in the box, pending this return before they give back the money they charged as security (to make sure you didn't try to rob them). Now, if all of the above fail, there are 2 things that could be the problem. One problem could be that your car doesn't support the iOS on the new iPod, or the car just wasn't made for adapting to new iPod versions.

Comment: I think Kristy is pursuing the right avenue in the first paragraph, but my first question would be "what is the Nano's volume setting?" I haven't tested the output voltage of a Nano, but with an original iPod, you wanted the volume set to full (in practice, I'd decrease it slightly) to get a line-level output from the headphone jack.

Comment: Thanks @jaberg, to be honest, I actually hadn't thought of that at all

Comment: Kristy—feel free to edit your answer to include this if you feel it's appropriate.

Comment: @jaberg Thanks, but no thanks, i don't feel it would be right to take any credit for your own answer.

Comment: Not a problem. You'd get the credit if I did the edit. At least for me, it's about answers, not reputation.